# Why is mock.patch class decorator not working?

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock something for an entire class but the following minimal example is not working:

```
import time
import six
if six.PY2:
    import mock
else:
    from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('time.sleep', mock.Mock(side_effect=Exception('dooooom')))
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print('before')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('after')

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

I get this unexpected output: (why did `time.sleep` not raise?)

```
before
after
```

However if I move the `@mock.patch(...)` down 1 line so it is decorating the method `bar` instead of the class `Foo` then it works as expected:

```
before
...
Exception: blah
```

Why does `@mock.patch` not work at the class level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the class decorator only patches methods beginning with `patch.TEST_PREFIX` which defaults to `test`.

So renaming the method to `test_bar` or even `testbar` makes the patch start working.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

> Patch can be used as a `TestCase` class decorator. It works by decorating each test method in the class. This reduces the boilerplate code when your test methods share a common patchings set. patch() finds tests by looking for method names that start with `patch.TEST_PREFIX`. By default this is `'test'`, which matches the way `unittest` finds tests. You can specify an alternative prefix by setting `patch.TEST_PREFIX`.

Evidently this behaviour applies to any class whether inheriting from `unittest.TestCase` or not.

Comment: I had the exact same problem - however, my method is already prefixed with "test_" and still isn't working.  (Works when I move the same decorator to the test function directly instead of the test class.)  Only difference is I'm trying to decorate a parent class - my `BaseTestCase`, which inherits from Django's `LiveServerTestCase`, and which I subclass in my test files.